# How to do a 2-step forecast in R?

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a time series where the first 1525 data points will be used to forecast the final 300 points in the series. I am using the forecast library but find close to no information on how to do a 2 step forecast. Here is a snippet of my data

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close
02/01/2004  17.96   18.68   17.54   18.22
05/01/2004  18.45   18.49   17.44   17.49
06/01/2004  17.66   17.67   16.19   16.73
07/01/2004  16.72   16.75   15.5    15.5
08/01/2004  15.42   15.68   15.32   15.61
09/01/2004  16.15   16.88   15.57   16.75
12/01/2004  17.32   17.46   16.79   16.82
13/01/2004  16.6    18.33   16.53   18.04
14/01/2004  17.29   17.3    16.4    16.75
15/01/2004  17.07   17.31   15.49   15.56
16/01/2004  15.4    15.44   14.9    15
20/01/2004  15.77   16.13   15.09   15.21
```

The code so far is basic just setting up for doing the forecast

```
r_vix_3b=diff(log(VIX[,"Close"]))
num_train=1526 
h=300
plot_start=1300 
plot_labels=126      # interval between x-axis major tick marks
data_fcst_pts=num_train:(num_train+h) 
fit_1step=auto.arima(r_vix_3b[1:num_train])
```

How is the 2-step forecast done? All input is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "2 step" forecast? I have never heard of a method referred to as a 2 step forecast. Most of the time the number of steps refers to how far out you want to make your forecast (e.g. forecasting one step ahead means forecasting for the very next time point)